# C# / wpf combobox templated item height

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am making a user control that has a button and a combo box in it. The combo box is read-only. I have a `DataTemplate` defined and the `ItemsSource` in the combo box is set to a list of doubles which equate to percentages of a value that I have defined as a dependency property in the user control. My intent is to display as each item, the percentage of the value in the user control.

Everything works fine except that the height of the items when the combo box's drop down is open are about twice the height of the combo box itself, and when I pick one, it sets the height of the user control to the size of the combo box.

[Unopened Combo Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvU7i.png)

[Combo Box after selecting item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgNmG.png)

If I leave out the template, the items in the combo box are sized to the original height of the combo box and the combo box remains at it's original height.

I would like the height of the items when the cobo's drop-down is opened to remain the size of the original combo box, and when I select an item from the drop-down, I do not wan the combo box to resize.

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FEAServer.UI.Controls.TorqueControl" Name="theControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:valconv="clr-namespace:FEAServer.Common.ValueConverters;assembly=FEAServer.Common.ValueConverters"
        xmlns:localconv="clr-namespace:FEAServer.UI.Controls.Converters"
        xmlns:localprops="clr-namespace:FEAServer.UI.Controls.Properties"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <valconv:UnitsOfMeasureConverter x:Key="UOMConv" />
    <localconv:TorquePercentageConverter x:Key="TorquePCTConv"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LoadCasesDataTemplate">
        <Label>
            <Label.Content>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TorquePCTConv}" ConverterParameter="{x:Static valconv:UnitsOfMeasureUnit.TORQUE}">
                    <Binding ElementName="theControl" Path="UnitsOfMeasure"/>
                    <Binding />
                    <Binding ElementName="theControl" Path="AnalysisTorque" />
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource UOMConv}" />
                    <Binding Source="{x:Static localprops:Resources.torqueFormatString}"/>
                </MultiBinding> 
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Name="cbSelectTorque" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding TorquePercentages}"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LoadCasesDataTemplate}"
              Margin="3,3,0,3">
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Name="btnUnits" Width="Auto" Height="{Binding ElementName=cbSelectTorque, Path=Height}"
            Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Click="btnUnits_Click">
        <Button.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UOMConv}" ConverterParameter="{x:Static Member=valconv:UnitsOfMeasureUnit.TORQUE}">
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding Path="UnitsOfMeasure" Mode="OneWay" />
                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
public partial class TorqueControl : UserControl
{
    bool _isTorqueConfigurable;

    public static DependencyProperty UnitsOfMeasureProperty = DependencyProperty.
        Register("UnitsOfMeasure", typeof(UnitsOfMeasureSystem), typeof(TorqueControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUnitsOfMeasureChanged)));

    public static DependencyProperty AnalysisTorqueProperty = DependencyProperty.
        Register("AnalysisTorque", typeof(double), typeof(TorqueControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAnalysisTorqueChanged)));

    public static DependencyProperty TorquePercentagesProperty = DependencyProperty.
        Register("TorquePercentages", typeof(ObservableCollection<double>), typeof(TorqueControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTorquePercentagesChanged)));

    public TorqueControl()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public UnitsOfMeasureSystem UnitsOfMeasure
    {
        get
        {
            return (UnitsOfMeasureSystem)GetValue(UnitsOfMeasureProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if ((UnitsOfMeasureSystem)GetValue(UnitsOfMeasureProperty) != value)
            {
                SetValue(UnitsOfMeasureProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }

    static void OnUnitsOfMeasureChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TorqueControl cont = d as TorqueControl;
        if(cont != null)
        {
            cont.UnitsOfMeasure = (UnitsOfMeasureSystem)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    public double AnalysisTorque
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(AnalysisTorqueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if ((double)GetValue(AnalysisTorqueProperty) != value)
            {
                SetValue(AnalysisTorqueProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }

    static void OnAnalysisTorqueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TorqueControl cont = d as TorqueControl;
        if (cont != null)
        {
            cont.AnalysisTorque = (double)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<double> TorquePercentages
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<double>)GetValue(TorquePercentagesProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if ((ObservableCollection<double>)GetValue(TorquePercentagesProperty) != value)
            {
                SetValue(TorquePercentagesProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }

    static void OnTorquePercentagesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TorqueControl cont = d as TorqueControl;
        if (cont != null)
        {
            cont.TorquePercentages = (ObservableCollection<double>)e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    public bool IsTorqueConfigurable
    {
        get
        {
            return _isTorqueConfigurable;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isTorqueConfigurable != value)
            {
                _isTorqueConfigurable = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private void btnUnits_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (UnitsOfMeasure == UnitsOfMeasureSystem.ENGLISH)
        {
            UnitsOfMeasure = UnitsOfMeasureSystem.METRIC;
        }
        else
        {
            UnitsOfMeasure = UnitsOfMeasureSystem.ENGLISH;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I originally posted this, I had tried all manner of binding the height of the label to the height of the combo box, the items control, etc, setting the Margin property, and on. After more searching, I found what works well enough for me. I set the "Padding" property of the Label to 0. MS' documentation for the Control.Padding property says that the default value is 0. In this case, something must have set it to a value other than 0. So, setting the Padding property to 0 overrides the value it was set to. When selecting the item, it does not resize the combobox.